# jQuery .height() property not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height

I'm attempting to get the height of an element using jQuery, but am receiving some unexpected results.  Here's the code:

```
$(function() { 
    var contentheight = $('#subpage-content-small').height;
    alert(contentheight);
});
```

Where #subpage-content-small has these CSS properties:

```
#subpage-content-small { width: 400px; float: left; margin: 30px 10px 0 0; padding-bottom: 45px; }
```

What I'm getting as an output for my alert is the following:

```
function (f) { var e = this[0]; if (!e) { return f == null ? null : this; } if (c.isFunction(f)) { return this.each(function (j) {var i = c(this);i[d](f.call(this, j, i[d]()));}); } return "scrollTo" in e && e.document ? e.document.compatMode === "CSS1Compat" &&  e.document.documentElement["client" + b] || e.document.body["client" + b] : e.nodeType === 9 ? Math.max(e.documentElement["client" + b], e.body["scroll" + b], e.documentElement["scroll" + b], e.body["offset" + b], e.documentElement["offset" + b]) : f === w ? c.css(e, d) : this.css(d, typeof f === "string" ? f : f + "px"); }
```

Any idea why I'm getting this as opposed to an integer of the height? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var contentheight = $('#subpage-content-small').height();
```

It's a function, not a property.

Comment: I blame 4/20 for missing this one. Thanks a mil!

Answer (score 4):

From jquery:

> The difference between .css('height')
>   and .height() is that the latter
>   returns a unit-less pixel value (for
>   example, 400) while the former returns
>   a value with units intact (for
>   example, 400px). The .height() method
>   is recommended when an element's
>   height needs to be used in a
>   mathematical calculation.

Try calling it as `height()` instead of `height`

Comment: Same as above. Thanks for catching that.